# Unable to convert from AdapterView to custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-adapter

In my app I have implemented a Navigation Drawer that displays a list of bank accounts for a checkbook. I have written an AccountAdapter class that handles this list, and in my NavigationDrawerFragment class use the following generated code:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(mAccountAdapter);
mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
        AccountAdapter adapter = (AccountAdapter) adapterView.getAdapter();
        Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToPosition(i)){
            // Do nothing!
        }
    }
});
```

However, I get an error on the first line of the `onItemClick` method:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter cannot be cast to com.example.android.checkit.AccountAdapter

Is this the proper way to handle an itemClick event for this listview? How can I adjust the code to avoid this error?

Comment: Have you tried declaring an actual type for `AdapterView<T>` instead of using a wildcard? Or you could at least try to bind it (T extends AccountAdapter) to ensure the cast will be possible. Also, AccountAdapter must extend the type you are trying to cast from (so the error is basically saying AccountAdapter does not derive from HeaderViewListAdapter)

Comment: No, it's actually just using the pre-generated code that Android Studio gave me. What type should be there?

Comment: @VinceEmigh well AccountAdapter extends CursorAdapter, so maybe I need to design a different `onItemClickListener` for the ListView? Sorry, I'm new to Android, so some of these little simple things aren't very intuitive to me.

Comment: It depends on how your code works. I'm not sure what needs to be handled in your listener, so you need to pick a type that suits your needs. Although, if you only want classes that are superclasses of AccountAdapter (since you are attempting to cast), you could do `? super AccountAdapter`. You should look into generics and type-casting.

Comment: I just looked at old source code for another project, it uses the same code as above but the Adapter we used there also extended Cursor Adapter so I don't know if that's really the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AccountAdapter adapter = (AccountAdapter) adapterView.getWrappedAdapter()` [(doc).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html)

update:

```
HeaderViewListAdapter headerViewAdapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) adapterView.getAdapter();
AccountAdapter adapter = (AccountAdapter) headerViewAdapter.getWrappedAdapter();
```

Comment: I can't do that. I'm really confused, it's not listed as one of the methods I can call on `adapterView`.

Comment: You should ALWAYS read the documentation of what you are using, especially when you run into problems; +1

Comment: This works, so thank you. I'm still not sure why I have this problem. I looked back at another project that has the exact same type of code and doesn't give me this error. But, I fixed it and this is only for a class project not a real application so I'll roll with what works.

Comment: It happens when you add a header or footer to your `ListView`.